# How can i use sed with unicode character

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line, terminal

```
function change() {
  for i in {0..28}
  do
    echo ",${cryp_data_letter[$i]}" "${org_data[$i]}"
    sed -i "s/,${cryp_data_letter[$i]}/${org_data[$i]}/g" "./temp.txt"
    #cat "./temp.txt"
  done
}
```

I have a function that change the some character in the temp.txt by a spesific rule but some kind of character like ı,ğ,ö etc. change with empty string. I suppose the cause of the trouble is UTF-8 so how can i apply sed with unicode? or any other suggestion for --> "sed -i "s/,${cryp_data_letter[$i]}/${org_data[$i]}/g" "./temp.txt""

Here is the given file temp.txt:

```
abc ğhıi
def
jkl
oöpr
uü vy z
çgm ns
şt
```

and output:

```
IDK ,ğS,ıT
NMY
BOÜ
G,öHÇ
P,ü ÖF ,
,çUŞ ZĞ
,şV
```

By the way, in return process i will change all letter with lower case and put "," before the all letter so it will become before the sed:

```
,a,b,c ,ğ,h,ı,i
,d,e,f
,j,k,l
,o,ö,p,r
,u,ü ,v,y ,z
,ç,g,m ,n,s
,ş,t
```

LOCALE:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=tr_TR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Would you be able to create a MCVE? For example, you can copy-paste `printf 'Hello,\xC3\xB6\n' > file; sed -i -e $'s/,\xC3\xB6/, world/' file; cat file` into your terminal and run it to see a UTF-8 `,ö` being successfully replaced with `, world`. Can you make something we can copy-paste into our terminals that show what you mean? (The code you posted doesn't declare `cryp_data_letter` or create `temp.txt`, so no one else can try it to debug)

Comment: sorry for the explanation i added the file content and also cryp_data_letter is an array that keep 29 character for alphabet. @thatotherguy

Comment: Also org_data is a different order of cryp_data_letter they are the same size.@thatotherguy

Comment: Please add output of `locale` to your question.

Comment: i added it @Cyrus

Comment: Your `temp.txt` only has lowercase characters, while your data arrays are uppercase. `sed` is case sensitive by default.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues here, which may each in isolation or combination cause your issue.

- We can't know which character set and encoding you use. Your locale is correctly set up for UTF-8 but your terminal and other software might not be interoperating correctly. Perhaps see also the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) for some background and diagnostics.
- Even if your system and utilities are generally UTF-8 compatible, there is no guarantee that your `sed` is. Many `sed` variants are still oblivious to Unicode, and there is no stable proposal for what exactly the behavior should be. Sometimes it makes sense to switch to a different language; many trivial `sed` scripts can easily be ported to run under `perl -CSD -p` with little or no changes.
- Even if everything else is working correctly, Unicode provides multiple ways to represent many accented characters. If your data contains *ö* as a single code point U+00E6 but your script contains the corresponding decomposed sequence, or vice versa, your `sed` script (probably) won't replace the alternate representation. Look for Unicode normalization.

With that out of the way, if the second point is sufficient, the following might actually work.

```
perl -CSD -pi~ e 'tr/AEİR...FJ/ABCÇ...YZ/' ./temp.txt
```

Notice the `-i~` option to do in-place editing but save a backup file. I have little confidence that this will work right off the bat without some modifications and probably clarifications from your side.

Comment: Didn't really mean to check Community Wiki but oh well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the non-answer, but I'm unable to reproduce your issue.

Here's your code in a completely self-contained script (please do this yourself next time):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ö != $'\xC3\xB6' ]]
then
  echo "You didn't save this file as UTF-8"
  exit 1
fi

function change() {
  for i in {0..28}
  do
#    echo ",${cryp_data_letter[$i]}" "${org_data[$i]}"
    sed -i "s/,${cryp_data_letter[$i]}/${org_data[$i]}/g" "./temp.txt"
    #cat "./temp.txt"
  done
}

# Shift all characters one letter ahead in the alphabet
cryp_data_letter=({a..z} ğ ö ı)
org_data=({b..z} ğ ö ı a)

# Create the file as you say it is before the sed
cat > temp.txt << "EOF"
,a,b,c ,ğ,h,ı,i
,d,e,f
,j,k,l
,o,ö,p,r
,u,ü ,v,y ,z
,ç,g,m ,n,s
,ş,t
EOF

change

cat temp.txt
```

When I run `./testscript` I get this output:

```
bcd öiaj
efg
klm
pıqs
v,ü wz ğ
,çhn ot
,şu
```

As you can see, the letters including the `ö` and `ğ` are being replaced and inserted just fine.